# Unable to create an array of Python objects from YAML

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to instantiate an array of python objects from YAML, inside a struct. Outside of a struct I am able to do this easily, but it seems that the YAML BaseLoader is failing to recursively search the sub nodes of my object.

```
import yaml
import ruamel.yaml

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str = 'JohnDoe'):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        if 'Name' in m:
            name = m['Name']

        return cls(name=name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person(name={self.name})'


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passengers = []

    def add_person(self, person: Person = None):
        self.passengers.append(person)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass

        inst = cls()

        if 'Driver' in m:
            inst.passengers = [m['Driver']]+inst.passengers

        if 'Passengers' in m:
            foo = m['Passengers']
            print(f'm[\'Passengers\'] = {foo}')
            for person in m['Passengers']:
                inst.add_person(person)

        return inst

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Car(passengers={self.passengers})'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    yaml.register_class(Person)
    yaml.register_class(Car)

    data = yaml.load("""
        - !Person &0
            Name: 'Paul'

        - !Person &1
            Name: 'George'
            
        - !Person &3
            Name: 'John'

        - !Car
            Driver: *0
            Passengers: [*1]

        - !Car
            Driver: *3
            Passengers: 
                - !Person &4
                    Name: 'Ringo'

        """)

    print(f'data = {data}')
```

the above code prints the following to the console on execution:

```
m['Passengers'] = []
m['Passengers'] = []
data = [Person(name=Paul), Person(name=George), Person(name=John), Car(passengers=[Person(name=Paul)]), Car(passengers=[Person(name=John)])]
```

where as I would expect the output to be

```
m['Passengers'] = [Person(name=George)]
m['Passengers'] = [Person(name=Ringo)]
data = [Person(name=Paul), Person(name=George), Person(name=John), Car(passengers=[Person(name=Paul), Person(name=George)]), Car(passengers=[Person(name=John), Person(name=Ringo)])]
```

no matter what, even with an array of strings, the associated value of the key 'Passengers' is always [] in the dictionary m.

do I have to manually tell the constructor to travers the rest of the node first in the from_yaml function, or does YAML loader work recursively from the bottom up?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a partial answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826576/how-do-i-handle-recursion-in-a-custom-pyyaml-constructor).

In the case of `raumel.yaml`, it looks like our constructor is the `from_yaml` function, which gets added when the class is registered. All we have to do is add a yield after the initialization of our class in `from_yaml`, and before we retrieve our recursive item `Passengers`.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passengers = []

    def add_person(self, person: Person = None):
        self.passengers.append(person)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):

        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            print(f'm{type(m)} = {m}')
            pass

        inst = cls()
        yield inst # <-- This yield statement fixes our issue

        if 'Driver' in m:
            inst.passengers = [m['Driver']]+inst.passengers

        if 'Passengers' in m:
            foo = m['Passengers']
            print(f'm[\'Passengers\'] = {foo}')
            for person in m['Passengers']:
                inst.add_person(person)
                
        return inst

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Car(passengers={self.passengers})'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `import yaml` in your example.

During the construction of the car, its passengers are not yet know. So
what you need to do is construct potentially recursive data such
as `Person` and `Car` in a two step process, first constructing and yielding the "empty" `Car`
then filling in the `Driver` and any `Passangers` on the already yielded instance. The loader knows
how to handle this, so you don't have to recurse into anything in your `from_yaml`.

Additionally you'll need to call `constructor.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)`
in `from_yaml`, instead of your iteration over `constructor.construct_yaml_map(node)`:

```py
import ruamel.yaml

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str = 'JohnDoe'):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        inst = cls()
        yield inst
        m = constructor.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
        if 'Name' in m:
            inst.name = m['Name']
     
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person(name={self.name})'


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passengers = []

    def add_person(self, person: Person = None):
        self.passengers.append(person)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        inst = cls()
        yield inst
        m = constructor.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)

        if 'Driver' in m:
            inst.passengers = [m['Driver']] + inst.passengers

        if 'Passengers' in m:
            foo = m['Passengers']
            print(f'm[\'Passengers\'] = {foo}')
            for person in m['Passengers']:
                inst.add_person(person)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Car(passengers={self.passengers})'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
    yaml.register_class(Person)
    yaml.register_class(Car)

    data = yaml.load("""
        - !Person &0
            Name: 'Paul'

        - !Person &1
            Name: 'George'
            
        - !Person &3
            Name: 'John'

        - !Car
            Driver: *0
            Passengers: [*1]

        - !Car
            Driver: *3
            Passengers: 
                - !Person &4
                    Name: 'Ringo'

        """)

    print(f'data = {data}')
```

which gives:

```
m['Passengers'] = [Person(name=George)]
m['Passengers'] = [Person(name=Ringo)]
data = [Person(name=Paul), Person(name=George), Person(name=John), Car(passengers=[Person(name=Paul), Person(name=George)]), Car(passengers=[Person(name=John), Person(name=Ringo)])]
```

Although it is allowed to write the tag followed by the anchor, it is IMO more appropriate to write the anchor
followed by the tag, because you'll get an anchored instance of the tagged object.

So that leaves me wondering what the name is of `&2 !Person` (probably the same as for `!Person &2`), is it Pete?